# How to view GBM package trees?

Tags: r, boosting

I am trying to view the output from the GBM package for boosted trees in R. Below I am fitting a single tree without any sampling in order to compare the tree to the complete dataset. First, create the data set:

```
  set.seed(1973)

############## CREATE DATA#############################################
N <- 1000
X1 <- runif(N)
X2 <- 2*runif(N)
X3 <- ordered(sample(letters[1:4],N,replace=TRUE),levels=letters[4:1])
X4 <- factor(sample(letters[1:6],N,replace=TRUE))
X5 <- factor(sample(letters[1:3],N,replace=TRUE))
X6 <- 3*runif(N)
mu <- c(-1,0,1,2)[as.numeric(X3)]

SNR <- 10 # signal-to-noise ratio
Y <- X1**1.5 + 2 * (X2**.5) + mu
sigma <- sqrt(var(Y)/SNR)
Y <- Y + rnorm(N,0,sigma)

# introduce some missing values
X1[sample(1:N,size=500)] <- NA
X4[sample(1:N,size=300)] <- NA

data <- data.frame(Y=Y,X1=X1,X2=X2,X3=X3,X4=X4,X5=X5,X6=X6)
########################################################################

#Fit model##############################################################
gbm1 <- gbm(Y~X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6, # formula
    data=data,                   # dataset
    var.monotone=c(0,0,0,0,0,0), # -1: monotone decrease,
                                 # +1: monotone increase,
                                 #  0: no monotone restrictions
    distribution="gaussian",     # bernoulli, adaboost, gaussian,
                                 # poisson, coxph, and quantile available
    n.trees=1,                   # number of trees
    shrinkage=1,                 # shrinkage or learning rate,
                                 # 0.001 to 0.1 usually work
    interaction.depth=1,         # 1: additive model, 2: two-way interactions, etc.
    bag.fraction = 1,            # subsampling fraction, 0.5 is probably best
    train.fraction = 1,          # fraction of data for training,
                                 # first train.fraction*N used for training
    n.minobsinnode = 10,         # minimum total weight needed in each node
    keep.data=TRUE,              # keep a copy of the dataset with the object
    verbose=TRUE)                # print out progress

###########################################################################
```

Next, look at the tree. This suggests, I think, a split on X2 at the value 1.5. However, this suggests 522 records one direction and 478 the other. Looking at the data, this record split does not correspond to the counts. Any insight? Is this a bug?

```
pretty.gbm.tree(gbm1,i.tree = 1)
length(d<-subset(data, data$X2>1.50,3)[,1])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a bug. The model is stored using a 0-based index. So SplitVar=0 is X1, SplitVar=1 is X2, and SplitVar=2 is X3. So this split corresponds to a split on X3. Since X3 is an ordinal factor and the split is at 1.5, this corresponds to splitting levels 0&1 from 2&3.

> sum(data$X3<="c")

[1] 522

> sum(data$X3>="b")

[1] 478